# What is the minimal codes to create my own \documentclass derived from LaTeX's book?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I want to invoke my document class as follows:

```
\documentclass[cymk,dvips,dvipsnames]{mybook}
```

Internally `mybook.cls` includes my own packages such as `mytables.sty`, `mypstricks.sty`, etc.

What is the minimal code to create this document class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\ProvidesClass{mybook}[2011/01/20 v 0.01 my own class (hv)]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}% or whatever
\ProcessOptions\relax
%
\LoadClass[% the default options
]{book}
\RequirePackage{xcolors}
\RequirePackage{...}
...
\endinput
```

And, of course, a comment statement of the license (LPPL) at the beginning, and preferrably some basic info about the file if you plan to ever publish it anywhere.

Comment: I was under the impression that classes need to have: \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[<date of some version>] as the first statement. Did you leave it out? Or am I in error? Thanks.

Comment: @bev: that is done by the loaded class and already nowadays no more a problem.