# Large document edited by a dozen people

Tags: compiling, input, include, collaboration

We, a team of 12 people, plan to write a 50 pages paper. The paper will be divided into chapters. Usually, no more than 2 or 3 people will work on a given chapter.

Having one large file will create problems when everyone will be editing and committing it in our VCS. I thought to split it into several files and input them. It works fine however one is still forced to compile the whole document. I could educate people to use `\includeonly` but we really want to use *input* and not *include*.

To alleviate this problem, I came up with the idea of extra "steering" files, one for each chapter, that does the same as the "main" file but only for a given chapter. It works but seems a bit cumbersome...

What is your feeling about it? 
How would you handle such a use case?

Comment: [`lipsum`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/lipsum) or [`kantlipsum`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/kantlipsum) the rest of the document,maybe?

Comment: etherpad perhaps?

Comment: Making specific main files for chapters sounds reasonable to me. If you put all the preamble stuff into a separate file, such a "chapter main file" will look like
`\input{preamble}  
    \begin{document}  
      \input{chapter_n}  
    \end{document}
`
which doesn't look cumbersome to me.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Indeed putting the preamble in a separate file would make things cleaner. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Why not having the different groups comment out the `\input`s of the other chapters in their local copy. Ok, you have to be careful not to commit this change into the VCS. However, you could still make an unversioned copy and use this as main file. As long the main file doesn't change often this is reasonable.

Comment: If you use a distributed VCS and each group works on only their chapter, then even using one file should not be a problem.  However, splitting the input is a good thing. As an aside: one useful technique is to use a mercurial repository in a shared Dropbox folder.  This also allows contributions from collaborators uncomfortable with a DVCS (I occasionally commit their changes for them).  You can also keep and share a master generated pdf of the complete final version for reference too.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Yes, I could have done it this way. You know, sometimes you get into complicated stuff for the beauty of it, and forget about the less fancy, yet functional, solutions. :)

Comment: @mforbes Interesting remark about dropbox. I'll think about it and do this in case of need.

Comment: My personal opinion is that Dropbox is very, very bad as a collaboration tool. Concurrent edits can cause you to lose your work: its behavior is basically "last person to click on save wins". The function to restore previous versions is not failproof, and history gets lost eventually. There are no diff tools as far as I know. In short, it seems to work well but it is not robust and when 12 people work on the same document it is quite likely that a catastrophe will happen sooner or later.

Comment: I invite the contributors to this question to take a look at one of my old questions, too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29577/splitting-a-large-document-into-several-files --- I haven't accepted an answer there because I don't find any of the arguments that were presented convincing; if you have a good reason to suggest in favor of splitting a document into several files, I will be happy to read it (and accept it as an answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, it is useful to put all of your prefactory material into a separate preamble.  I usually make a [custom class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9326/6903) to contain all of the required packages, formatting information, etc.

Write each chapter as a completely separate document, and then – as Martin Scharrer pointed out – you can use one of the following packages to allow you to directly `\input` these chapters in the master document:

- [`docmute`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/docmute): A minimal package providing just enough to allow you to include standalone chapters in the main document.
- [`combine`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/combine): A more comprehensive set of classes and packages designed for combining conference proceedings.  Provides more functionality for dealing with titles and bibliographies.
- [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone): When used as a package, this works very similarly to `docmute` but provides much more functionality, such as the `standalone` class which crops the output.
- [`subfiles`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles): Similar functionality to `docmute` but requires a slightly modified usage format (`\subfile{}` instead of `\input{}` etc.)

The class `myclass.cls` should look something like this:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2012/06/01 v1 Custom class for ... project]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}% or whatever
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{scrbook}

% Include whatever packages you need here...

% Use either one of these:
\RequirePackage{standalone}
%\RequirePackage{docmute}
```

Now your chapters can look and behave like like self-contained documents:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
Here is the first chapter
\end{document}
```

and your master file can input these like

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\input{chapter2.tex}
\end{document}
```

The packages modify the outer `document` so that the inner `\documentclass` and `document` environments in each of the `\input` chapters have no effect.

Comment: There are already several package which do this: `docmute`, `standalone` and at least one more I can't recall.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I did not realize that ``standalone`` et al. worked this way too! I will include this.

Comment: Very nice. I don't understand however where I have to put the first code you show (ProvideClass...). In a file myclass.sty ?

Comment: @Barth: Put the first code in a file ``myclass.cls``, then each chapter into files ``chapter1.tex``, ``chapter2.tex`` etc. and finally the last code in ``master.tex``.  Then run ``latex master`` to generate the whole shebang, or ``latex chapter1`` to generate just the first chapter.

Comment: It works perfectly with docmute. Simple but powerful. Thank you very much. I will accept this answer as it is what I am going to use.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: The/a missing one is probably [`subfiles`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles). I have used it successfully for a couple of collaborative projects. @mbforbes: I suggest adding this to your list.

Comment: @Daniel: I looked at ``subfiles`` and must admit that I do not see why it would be an improvement over ``docmute``.  The latter allows both the subfiles and master files to look like normal LaTeX documents, whereas ``subfiles`` requires the new ``\subfile{}`` command (instead of ``\input{}``) and each subfile must use the ``subfiles`` documentclass (which means they cannot stand alone).  Am I missing and advantage?

Comment: Well, I don't know `docmute` and do not claim `subfiles` to be superior in any respect. It's just that this one is often mentioned for the task in question so I suggested to add it to the list for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @mforbes, are the packages you mentioned still up to date?  Has any one being deprecated or superseded by a new one?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Martin's [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package is definitely kept up to date.  I would suggest following the links to CTAN to see when they were updated last: I do not use the others now so don't know of any incompatibility issues etc.

Answer (score 6):

In ConTeXt you can create an *environment* file (the layout) and several *components* (the individual chapters). The components are linked to the environment. That way you can complile one chapter, parts of it or the entire document.

The details are explained in the [ConTeXt wiki - Project Structure](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure) or in the [Project Structure manual](http://pragma-ade.com/general/magazines/mag-1101.pdf).

Here is an example of how the structure looks:

```
% file: introduction.tex
\startcomponent introduction
\project paper
  \startchapter [title=Introduction]
  \stopchapter
\stopcomponent

% file: theory.tex
\startcomponent theory
\project paper
  \startchapter [title=Theory]
  \stopchapter
\stopcomponent

% file: main.tex
\startproduct main
\project paper
  \component introduction
  \component theory
\stopproduct

% file: environ.tex
\startenvironment environ
  \setupbodyfont [palatino]
\stopenvironment

% file: project.tex
\startproject project
  \environment environ
\stopproject
```

The project file is a way to gather common inclusions: it links to environment files using `\environment`, so that `\startproduct` and `\startcomponent` blocks can use `\project` to include all the project's environment files at once. You can also always include environment files directly in the file if needed.

Using this setup, you can compile the individual chapters with `context introduction…` and the entire document with `context main`.

Comment: Context seems very powerful and useful. I'll have a look at it asap. For now I 'll go with the simple solution proposed by mforbes. Thank you.