# Different styles and classes (my own + IEEEtran)

Tags: ieeetran, report

I'm writing my thesis based on `documentclass{report}`.  It uses my own style (some other information about it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107008/27833)), and everything works just fine.

Now, according to my University requirements, I should include ---as appendix--- in my dissertation the papers I wrote while doing it.  These papers are also written in LaTeX, but they are written using the `documentclass{IEEEtran}`, which, of course, uses its own IEEE style depending if it is an article or conference proceedings.

My question is, can I used any of the packages mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58616/27833) to include the code of my papers in my thesis?  Is it going to be any problem with the `hyperrref` package or any other for that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve appears to be quite a hassle, as the individual parts of your document will have totally different styles. Here's a suggestion that mitigates that problem: just include the papers that you published as-they-are (i.e., as PDFs). That's relatively simple and will let you achieve what you want to do.

Some more details can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739159/inserting-a-pdf-file-in-latex